# why virtual function give segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, runtime-error, virtual-functions

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 

/*
 *   base class
 */ 
class A
{
 public: 
    A()
    {
        this->init(); 
    }

    virtual void init()
    {
        cout << " A"; 
    }
    // in public, so class B can call it. 
    void testit()
    {
        this->init(); 
    }
}; 

/*
 * child class
*/ 
class B : public A
{
public:
    B()
    {
       this->init(); 
    }

    virtual void init()
    {
        // here get segmentation fault. 
        // but if call A::init() then it is ok. 
        A::testit();
        // if call A::init(); then it working. 
        cout << "B" ; 
    }

}; 

int main()
{   

      B b; 
      A * a = &b; 
      // here B virtual function will be called. 
      a->init(); 
      return 0; 

}
```

Basically this is a virtual function test. But I found when child class call base class function inside its own virtual function, it get runtime segmentation fault. why?

here when run time it get segmentation fault since at A::testit()
but why?

why child instance call base function get error?

Answer (score 1):

```
// but if call A::init() then it is ok. 
A::testit();
```

You're calling `init()` in `A::testit()`. `init()` is virtual, then `B::init()` will be called recursively when the current actual object is `B`, and becomes infinite recursion at last.

If you call `A::init()` explicitly infinite recursion will be avoided then it'll be ok.

Answer (score 1):

In short, the segmentation fault is due to endless recursion. `B::init` calls `A::testit`, which calls the object's `init`. Since the object is of class `B`, this means that `A::testit` will call `B::init`, which will call `A::testit`, and so on endlessly.

Why does it do this and not call `A::init` explicitly? Well, it's a case of polymorphism. In this situation, the `this` pointer inside of `B::init` points towards an object of class `B`. Since `B` has overwritten `A`'s virtual `init` method, any calls to that object's `init` will be calling the overwritten method in `B`. So `B::init()` is calling `A::testit()`, which calls `B::init()` in an endless loop. To call the parent's version of `init`, you have to call it explicitly (`A::init`).

Comment: It should be noted that `B::init` will NOT be called when the object's `init` method is called inside of `A`'s constructor or destructor.  This is because the `this` pointer does not point at an object of class `B` at those stages, it points at an object of class `A` instead, so any call to `init` will call `A::init` instead.  Polymorphism does not dispatch virtual method calls to derived classes in constructors and destructors, because derived classes do not exist at those stages.